# How can I completely disable the on-board LEDs on my ASUS motherboard?

Tags: installation, motherboard, bios, led

I have an ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming [motherboard](https://content.hwigroup.net/images/products_xl/316437/2/asus-z170-pro-gaming.jpg). When I bought it, I did not realize it annoying always-on red LEDs:

[image]

Now, these can be turned off using the BIOS, but - that doesn't "stick". They tend to revert somehow to being on (and certainly if you reset your BIOS settings). Is there something more, shall we say, definite or permanent I can do to turn off these LEDs?

Comment: black insulating tape.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You can make that an answer, I think. Also, won't it heat up with the glue-y material eventually melting over the board?

Comment: It was a slightly flippant comment, I'll admit, but - Insulating tape tends to go gooey over time anyway, but if left even longer then re-solidifies. It's not a perfect solution [to anything, really ;) but unless it's on a hot component you can probably safely leave it until it peels off far enough to see the lights again, then replace it. I'll throw it in as an answer in case no-one comes up with a permanent BIOS solution.

Answer (score 1):

After comments, I'll turn my slightly flippant comment into an answer...

Black insulating tape.
The glue will soften over time, but eventually re-harden. If it's not on a hot component [which I wouldn't recommend] then it will probably last a year or so before it peels away far enough to see the lights again - by which time either you moved to a new computer or you can put another piece of tape on.

In the absence of a true BIOS-based solution, it's a cheap, semi-permanent fix.